# is it appropriate to implement auto update for a c# application just by passing download url to msiexec

Tags: c#, windows-installer, clickonce, setup-project, auto-update

I have a project in c# which requires auto update functionality, since it has quite a lot of dependencies and runs a Windows service, ClickOnce installer is not suitable for this work. So I created a setup project for this application. Now I want to include an auto update feature.

My auto-update strategy is:

1. From the main application, check for updates every morning.
2. If an update is found, get the msi link
3. Application passes control to the msiexec and quits

Ex.

```
msiexec /i http://www.example.com/share/package.msi /L*V "C:\log\example.log"
```

Since my application is running on administrator account UAC prompt will not occur.

Are there any pitfalls that I haven't seen? Or there any superior way to do auto update gracefully?

Note: The setup project of the application is marked with the property RemoveAllPreviousVersion = True so it will take care of the uninstallation of previous versions.

Comment: Off-topic: The method you describe allows for man-in-the-middle attacks where your website may be spoofed and thus force clients to download and install a malicious package.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments/answers:

"Note: The setup project of the application is marked with the property RemoveAllPreviousVersion = True so it will take care of the uninstallation of previous versions."

But only if you increment the Version property of the setup project, accept the change in ProductCode, keep the UpgradeCode the same, ensure that the value of EveryOne or Just me is the same in the older product and the upgrade, and increase the file versions of files you need to update.

It's also not obvious to me that you won't get a UAC prompt because "running on an administrator account" does not mean the same as "running with administrator privilege". If the running process is not running elevated a prompt will occur, because UAC means that even administrators are running limited unless explicitly elevated. Even if you are elevated, calling msiexec as an external shell call will not result in msiexec being elevated. A shell execute does not transfer privilege to the offspring process. The other thing to consider is whether it's the current interactive user that is effectively doing this update, because there may be an issue trying to show UI if another user owns the desktop.

Anyway in general it's ok to do that, it's quite common, and signing the MSI would be more secure. Also, Windows Installer will sometimes prompt a repair, so that install URL needs to remain valid. A better approach would be for you to download the MSI to a location on the client system that you own and prompt the user to run it, or you run it - it's more friendly to offer that than pull the rug out and just do it.